# JQuery generic multiple buttons click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, generics, button, click

Brand new in JQuery and JS. I'm trying to handle button clicks in one generic function, that gets wich button was clicked and calls another function.
This is my current code:

```
 function add(el) {
            var button = $(el).attr('id');
            var infoForm;
            switch (button) {
                case "addEndereco":
                    infoForm = $("#infoEndereco");
                    break;
                case "addContato":
                    infoForm = $("#infoContato");
                    break;
                case "addBanco":
                    infoForm = $("#infoBanco");
                    break;
            }
            $(button).on('click', function () {
                gravarDetalhe(infoForm, button);
            });
        }
```

These are my button in my view:

```
<button id="addEndereco" type="button" OnClick="add(this);" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
<button type="button" id="addContato"  OnClick="add(this);" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
<button type="button" id="addBanco"  OnClick="add(this);" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
```

It's not working, I've done a research and tried a lot of things but nothing has helped.
What am I doing wrog here?

Comment: Can you please create a FIDDLE?

Comment: Where is defined the `gravarDetalhe` function? What did you try and why it didn't worked? What are the errors in console? Can you provide a live example to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just calling the `function` .. Why again `click handler`..

```
function add(el) {
                var button = $(el).attr('id');
                var infoForm;
                switch (button) {
                    case "addEndereco":
                        infoForm = $("#infoEndereco");
                        break;
                    case "addContato":
                        infoForm = $("#infoContato");
                        break;
                    case "addBanco":
                        infoForm = $("#infoBanco");
                        break;
                }
                //$(button).on('click', function () {
                    gravarDetalhe(infoForm, button);
                //});
            }
```

Comment: _Why again click handler.._ althought that wont bind anything to any element as the selector is wrong.